# How to create a signiture(hash) for a row in mysql table by trigger

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

Ive considered if is it possible to create a trigger before insert, update and delete commands that will hash cetrain fields including a unique pass phrase, so the only way to commit these commands is by creating the right hash, by giving wrong hash the insert/update/delete will be failed.
I succeed to do it for a trigger 'before update' here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `bu_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON  `item` FOR EACH ROW 
IF SHA1( NEW.item | NEW.info | '12387gdasdcc' ) <> NEW.sig THEN SET 
NEW.item = OLD.item;
SET NEW.info = OLD.info;
END IF
```

What this trigger do is checking if the given signiture 'NEW.sig' is exact as it should be, if its not, we wont let it change.
However i dont know how to do it for insert and delete commands, is it even possible?
On delete command for example there are no inputs exept in the 'WHERE' condition.
Do you have any suggestions how to guard my DB against unauthorised access?
Im trying to do that if an hacker will try to make any changes in a table he wont be able to do that until he will build up EXACTLY the same hash the trigger builds.

Comment: If the hacker obtains access to the credentials you application uses to connect, he is likely to be able to obtain the hash key too (you will need to put the hash key somewhere in your app).

Comment: I know but it just giving another layer of protection, that the app is the only thing that permitted to make any changes. You create an hash on your app and activates the command, the app as well as the trigger 'know' the passphrase, but the hacker musnt know it. He might try hashing different combinations for the fields value but he  also need the pass phrase which should be secret.

Comment: I guess you will need to create a stored proc for deleting with the hash as an additional parameter.

Comment: What about insert command? and how do I let delete commands execute only by this proc?. For some reason i couldnt execute the 'rollback' command.

Comment: Inserts should work the same way updates do. For allowing deletes only trough a stored proc - I don't know how to do it in oracle, but I'm pretty sure its possible.